# Visibility timeout in Amazon SQS not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, jms, message-queue, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

How do I configure visibility timeout so that a message in SQS can be read again?

I have Amazon SQS as a message queue. Messages are being sent by multiple applications. I am now using Spring listener to read message in queue as below:

```java
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerContainer() {
        
        SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()  
                .withAWSCredentialsProvider(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .withEndpoint(environment.getProperty("aws_sqs_url"))
                .withAWSCredentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(10).build();
        
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        dmlc.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
        dmlc.setDestinationName(environment.getProperty("aws_sqs_queue"));
        dmlc.setMessageListener(queueListener);
                
        return dmlc;
    }
```

The class `queueListener` implements `javax.jms.MessageListener` which uses `onMessage()` method further.

I have also configured a scheduler to read the queue again after a certain period of time. It uses `receiveMessage()` of `com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS`.

As soon as message reach the queue the listener reads the message. I want to read the message again after certain period of time i.e. through scheduler, but once a message is read by listener it does not become visible or read again. As per Amazon's SQS developer guide the default visibility timeout is 30 seconds, but that message is not becoming visible even after 30 seconds. I have tried setting custom visibility timeout in SQS QUEUE PARAMETER CONSOLE, but it's not working.

For information, nobody is deleting the message from the queue.

Comment: _Why_ are you wanting to intentionally read the same message again? The invisibility timeout is intended to handle messages that have failed during processing (eg a worker dies before completing the task). What is your particular use-case that requires reading the same message multiple times?

Comment: In case the message read and processed successfully, i am deleting it from queue. But, if there is any failure in processing the message or thread/server gets killed during execution i.e. before the manual trigger to delete the message, i want to read the message again to process again.

Comment: Good. That sounds like the normal process. As per Justin's answer below, it sounds like the message is auto-deleting due to the library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a passing familiarity with Amazon SQS, but I can say that typically in messaging use-cases when a consumer receives and *acknowledges* the message then that message is removed (i.e. deleted) from the queue. Given that your Spring application is receiving the message I would suspect it is also acknowledging the message and therefore removing it from the queue which prevents your scheduler from receiving it later. Note that Spring's `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` uses JMS' `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode by default.

[This documentation from Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html) essentially states that if a message is acknowledged in a JMS context that it is "deleted from the underlying Amazon SQS queue."